# Moving 72TB images sequences via Rsync

Tags: rsync

I have a task where I need to produce a duplicate of 72TB of images sequences from a film project. I would estimate that I have 6.5 million 11MB images.

Source drive is a RAID5 SAS that can read and write at 1000MB/s and the same is true for the destination RAID5 SAS.

My test 100GB video file does move from the SOURCE to the DESTINATION at the speeds listed above.

RSYNC 3.2.6 using -avb is currently getting 211MB/s max.

Is there any benefit to explore having TAR make a 20GB (chose that at random for illustration) uncompressed zip and pipe it to RSYNC to bring down the overhead of having to deal with so many small files?

Current task is set to take 4-5 days and I would like to shorten it.

Any input is welcome!

Mac OS 12.3
M1 Studio Ultra

Comment: Your `rsync` is moving data at about 1.7Gb/sec so you must have a multi-gb network in place. Is this a 10Gb network and what is the topology for the intermediate switches?

Comment: This is a TB3 SAS (on one bus) copying to another TB3 SAS (on another bus). No NIC's are being used.

Comment: What is the RAID5 made of? SSDs or spinning disks?

Comment: Yes 6 spinners.

Comment: Also since a few people answering have been unclear: SOURCE and DEST are on the same computer? No network involved?

Answer (score 1):

You're currently limited by seeking to, and reading/writing a bunch of small files. *Having* a bunch of 20GB .zip/.tar files would help. *Making* them will probably be even slower than rsync, because `zip` will have to do the same thing (random-access reads). But don't take my word for it. Pause rsync and test! Testing is pretty much always the right answer.

On Linux I'd recommend the tool `iostat` to see what fraction of time is being spent waiting on a disk. I'm not sure what the OS X equivalent is if you're using that.

If you wanted the entire source and destination RAIDs to be *identical* at the end (which given the `-b` option, you don't), you could instead use something like `dd` on the raid devices, which will run at 1000MB/s. But make sure you know **exactly** what you're doing with dd, or you may destroy your data.

If this is something you do often, consider running rsync repeatedly as you generate the images, so you don't have a 4-day wait at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The main speedups I've used for rsync streams:

1. Divide the list of files and run parallel rsync streams between the source and destination computers.  This usually provides a pretty large gain in throughput.
2. Remove ssh as the transport.  The encrypt/decrypt stages have some overhead.  If it's safe (not often true nowdays), then connecting an rsync client to an (unencrypted) rsync daemon can lift the throughput a good amount.
3. Already asked by you and addressed in another answer:  increasing the average file size can help some, especially if the data is compressible and you can spend the time compressing before the data is transmitted and decompressing afterward.  (and you have the extra storage space for it)  The time invested in compress/decompress stages can reduce the time during the transfer stage.

It's pretty rare that a single TCP stream (i.e. a lone rsync transfer) can reach maximum throughput through network links 1Gbps and faster.  Parallel transfers is most likely to make the largest difference.  There are a few programs on the Internet that advertise they can run parallel rsyncs.  I've tried to write my own, without much success.  It's a task that's more complex than it appears.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have broken up the files in to two folders now and am currently running two parallel RSYNC commands. Strangely, it takes RSYNC about 45min to ramp up to 230MB/s for these image sequences but they are both ramping at the same acceleration right now. Will report back. 15TB/72TB transfered.